# How to list Wordpress Password Protected Pages?

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-theming

Is there anyway in wordpress to return a sorted list of all the password protected pages in a wordpress site?

If so how do I go about this?

I basically want one page showing a list of all the pages that are password protected...

Thanks! :)

Answer (score 0):

I think this is the simplest answer to the question:

```
$page_ids = get_posts( [
    'post_type'      => 'page',
    'has_password'   => true,
    'posts_per_page' => - 1,
    'post_status'    => 'any',
    'fields'         => 'ids',
] );

wp_list_pages( 'include=' . implode( ',', $page_ids ) );
```

If you want to create your own list:

```
$page_ids = get_posts( [
    'post_type'      => 'page',
    'has_password'   => true,
    'posts_per_page' => - 1,
    'post_status'    => 'any',
    'fields'         => 'ids',
] );

foreach ( $page_ids as $page_id ) {
    // get_permalink( $page_id );
}
```

This is just a starting point.
You can play with `get_posts` or `WP_Query` to achieve better results.

Answer (score -1):

```
// Filter to hide protected posts
function exclude_protected($where) {
    global $wpdb;
    return $where .= " AND {$wpdb->posts}.post_password = '' ";
}

// Decide where to display them
function exclude_protected_action($query) {
    if( !is_single() && !is_page() && !is_admin() ) {
        add_filter( 'posts_where', 'exclude_protected' );
    }
}

// Action to queue the filter at the right time
add_action('pre_get_posts', 'exclude_protected_action');
```

I'd suggest using a filter, the piece of code above will exclude all password protected posts, with some editing you'll be able to get all password protected posts.

More info: https://codex.wordpress.org/Using_Password_Protection#Hiding_Password_Protected_Posts

Comment: Gimme an example using `WP_Query` object that will return `password protected` sorted `pages` (logged in/out) and this will only return the posts whose status are private. Also read the question `I basically want one page showing a list of all the pages that are password protected..` and `post_status:'private' - not visible to users who are not logged in.`

Comment: Hi, I want users who are not logged in to be able to see a list of all the password protected posts. On a page... The user that is not logged in can then click on the page they want to view and enter the password they have been provided with. It will be used for a client image gallery... Thanks for the reply!

Comment: @myatix, You asked for password protected pages in your question but here you mentioned about `posts` instead, anyways, check my answer and just change the `post_type = 'post'` to show pages or leave it if you want to show posts. Put the code in a page template that you  are using to show the list.

Comment: My apologies, it was to my understanding that "private" was "password protected" but this was not the case. I've edited my answer accordingly.